# I can't get pandas to union my dataframes properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try and concat or append (neither are working) 2 9-column dataframes together. But, instead of just doing a normal vertical stacking of them, pandas keeps trying to add 9 more empty columns as well. Do you know how to stop this?

**output** looks like this:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,0,1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
10/23/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,0.00,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10/22/2020,Wilmington,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.00,48,48,0,Ken,(903) 280-7878,UrTruckBroker ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.00,47,1,0,Dispatch,(912) 748-3801,DSV Road Inc. ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.00,48,1,0,Dispatch,(541) 826-4786,Sureway Transportation Co / Anderson Trucking Serv ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10/30/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,945.00,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

...


,,,,,,,,,,,,,,03/02/2021,Knapp,0.0,Dispatch,(763) 432-3680,Fuze Logistics Services USA ,WI,Jackson,NE,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.0,48.0,48.0
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,03/02/2021,Knapp,0.0,Dispatch,(763) 432-3680,Fuze Logistics Services USA ,WI,Sterling,IL,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.0,48.0,48.0
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,03/02/2021,Milwaukee,0.0,Dispatch,(763) 432-3680,Fuze Logistics Services USA ,WI,Great Falls,MT,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.0,45.0,48.0
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,03/02/2021,Algoma,0.0,Dispatch,(763) 432-3680,Fuze Logistics Services USA ,WI,Pamplico,SC,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.0,48.0,48.0
```

**code** is a web request to get data, which I save to dataframe, which is then concat-ed with another dataframe that comes from a CSV. I then save all of this back to that csv:

```
this_csv = 'freights_trulos.csv'

try:
  old_df = pd.read_csv(this_csv)
except BaseException as e:
  print(e)
  old_df = pd.DataFrame()

state, equip = 'DE', 'Flat'
url = "https://backend-a.trulos.com/load-table/grab_loads.php?state=%s&equipment=%s" % (state, equip)

payload = {}
headers = {
...
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# print(response.text)
parsed = json.loads(response.content)

data = [r[0:13] + [r[-4].split('<br/>')[-2].split('>')[-1]] for r in parsed]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

if not old_df.empty:
  # concatenate old and new and remove duplicates
  
  
  # df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)    
  # old_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
  # df = pd.concat([old_df, df], ignore_index=True)   <--- CONCAT HAS SAME ISSUES AS APPEND
  df = df.append(old_df, ignore_index=True)
  # remove duplicates on cols

df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_csv(this_csv, index=False)
```

**EDIT  appended df's have had their types changed**

```
df.dtypes
Out[2]: 
0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
dtype: object
old_df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7     float64
8       int64
9       int64
10      int64
11     object
12     object
13     object
dtype: object
```

old_df to csv

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
10/23/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,0.0,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency 
10/22/2020,Wilmington,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.0,48,48,0,Ken,(903) 280-7878,UrTruckBroker 
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.0,47,1,0,Dispatch,(912) 748-3801,DSV Road Inc. 
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.0,48,1,0,Dispatch,(541) 826-4786,Sureway Transportation Co / Anderson Trucking Serv 
10/30/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,945.0,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency
```

new_df to csv

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
10/23/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,0.00,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency 
10/22/2020,Wilmington,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed / Step Deck,0.00,48,48,0,Ken,(903) 280-7878,UrTruckBroker 
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.00,47,1,0,Dispatch,(912) 748-3801,DSV Road Inc. 
10/23/2020,WILMINGTON,DE,METHUEN,MA,Full,Flatbed w/Tarps,0.00,48,1,0,Dispatch,(541) 826-4786,Sureway Transportation Co / Anderson Trucking Serv 
10/30/2020,New Castle,DE,Gary,IN,Full,Flatbed,945.00,46,48,0,Dispatch,(800) 488-1860,Meadow Lark Agency
```

Comment: please provide sample input of df and old_df

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues with the `df.append` call.  Can you inspect and post the contents of `data`?

Comment: @Andreas I see column 6 changed data type or somehow (maybe other cols too). There was one decimal, now two. Is this what is causing issue, and if so, do you know how I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem could be how you read the data if I copy your sample data to excel and split by comma and then import to pandas, all is fine. Also if I split on comma AND whitespaces, I have +9 additional columns. So you could try debugging by replacing all whitespaces before creating your dataframe.

I also used your sample data and it workend just fine for me if I initialize it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: '10/23/2020',
  1: '10/22/2020',
  2: '10/23/2020',
  3: '10/23/2020',
  4: '10/30/2020'},
 '1': {0: 'New_Castle',
  1: 'Wilmington',
  2: 'WILMINGTON',
  3: 'WILMINGTON',
  4: 'New_Castle'},
 '2': {0: 'DE', 1: 'DE', 2: 'DE', 3: 'DE', 4: 'DE'},
 '3': {0: 'Gary', 1: 'METHUEN', 2: 'METHUEN', 3: 'METHUEN', 4: 'Gary'},
 '4': {0: 'IN', 1: 'MA', 2: 'MA', 3: 'MA', 4: 'IN'},
 '5': {0: 'Full', 1: 'Full', 2: 'Full', 3: 'Full', 4: 'Full'},
 '6': {0: 'Flatbed',
  1: 'Flatbed_/_Step_Deck',
  2: 'Flatbed_w/Tarps',
  3: 'Flatbed_w/Tarps',
  4: 'Flatbed'},
 '7': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 945.0},
 '8': {0: 46, 1: 48, 2: 47, 3: 48, 4: 46},
 '9': {0: 48, 1: 48, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 48},
 '10': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 '11': {0: 'Dispatch', 1: 'Ken', 2: 'Dispatch', 3: 'Dispatch', 4: 'Dispatch'},
 '12': {0: '(800)_488-1860',
  1: '(903)_280-7878',
  2: '(912)_748-3801',
  3: '(541)_826-4786',
  4: '(800)_488-1860'},
 '13': {0: 'Meadow_Lark_Agency_',
  1: 'UrTruckBroker_',
  2: 'DSV_Road_Inc._',
  3: 'Sureway_Transportation_Co_/_Anderson_Trucking_Serv_',
  4: 'Meadow_Lark_Agency_'}})


df_new = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: '10/23/2020',
  1: '10/22/2020',
  2: '10/23/2020',
  3: '10/23/2020',
  4: '10/30/2020'},
 '1': {0: 'New_Castle',
  1: 'Wilmington',
  2: 'WILMINGTON',
  3: 'WILMINGTON',
  4: 'New_Castle'},
 '2': {0: 'DE', 1: 'DE', 2: 'DE', 3: 'DE', 4: 'DE'},
 '3': {0: 'Gary', 1: 'METHUEN', 2: 'METHUEN', 3: 'METHUEN', 4: 'Gary'},
 '4': {0: 'IN', 1: 'MA', 2: 'MA', 3: 'MA', 4: 'IN'},
 '5': {0: 'Full', 1: 'Full', 2: 'Full', 3: 'Full', 4: 'Full'},
 '6': {0: 'Flatbed',
  1: 'Flatbed_/_Step_Deck',
  2: 'Flatbed_w/Tarps',
  3: 'Flatbed_w/Tarps',
  4: 'Flatbed'},
 '7': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 945.0},
 '8': {0: 46, 1: 48, 2: 47, 3: 48, 4: 46},
 '9': {0: 48, 1: 48, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 48},
 '10': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 '11': {0: 'Dispatch', 1: 'Ken', 2: 'Dispatch', 3: 'Dispatch', 4: 'Dispatch'},
 '12': {0: '(800)_488-1860',
  1: '(903)_280-7878',
  2: '(912)_748-3801',
  3: '(541)_826-4786',
  4: '(800)_488-1860'},
 '13': {0: 'Meadow_Lark_Agency_',
  1: 'UrTruckBroker_',
  2: 'DSV_Road_Inc._',
  3: 'Sureway_Transportation_Co_/_Anderson_Trucking_Serv_',
  4: 'Meadow_Lark_Agency_'}})

df_new.append(df_old, ignore_index=True)
#OR
pd.concat([df_new, df_old])
```